# Heroku Build API can't fetch source code

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to update my app on heroku using [node heroku client](https://github.com/jclem/node-heroku-client/blob/master/docs/build.md), but it fails with the message

```
Unable to fetch source from: https://my-aws-account.s3.amazonaws.com/source.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Expires=...&Signature=...
```

The source code gzipped tarball is public and fresh during the deploy.

The node-heroku-client seems to follow [build api](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build-create) properly. This error occurs after the build has began.

It seems to be a bug on heroku build servers, but I would like to know if someone else had this problem before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with at heroku, the upstream provider is working on fix  https://status.heroku.com/